# Any method to get stateless pagination in cassandra?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

Lets assume that I have a web Service , and I have a method that returns a set of records for a Web Page. This method get 1 parameter , it is the paging number so I can feed the number and get the results for that page number

if you take StackOverflow for an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=4)

it has a URL parameter when viewing all questions,
so what is the way to achieve this using Cassandra if my records are sorted using a clustering key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this page in our doc](http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/features/paging/) (use the dropdown at the top left corner to switch to your driver version).

In short: Cassandra supports saving the state of the previous page and using it to restart from the next page.

Offset queries (start from a random page) are not supported out of the box; there are ways to emulate them, provided that you accept a performance hit (basically skipping the first n results each time).

Comment: one more quick thing about this, Can I save paging states and use them again, lets say I want the 5th page , I load the paging state from where its saved and use that paging state. will it work, even though amount of records in the table changes?

Comment: The paging state is built from: the current partition key, the current cell name (which is basically the id of the current row), and the number of remaining rows if your query had a LIMIT. So with a given paging state you will always restart from the same row. If rows were added/removed in the meantime, that might be a different row than what you would get if you re-iterated the 5 pages from the beginning.

Comment: Suppose due to some exception (say `ReadTimeoutException`) the resultset i get is null and hence i cant get the PagingState object, but I want to skip this page and still move to next page. Is there any way to do this? How can I move to next page in this case?

Comment: @abi_pat you can't. If you didn't get the paging state from the server, there is no way to generate it on the client.